# Magento 2.3 : Default feature Gift Cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, gift-card

According to the official doc, there is a gift card feature available in Magento 2.3
But when I go through the Admin Panel (catalog->products), There is no product created as a gift card as mentioned in Step 1 (https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/product-gift-card-create.html).

Still, I am confused so, I had to google Many blogs out of which some say it was there in an earlier version & some say it is still there in version 2.3. Also, I have checked the official doc which link is mentioned above. Can someone help me out to sort my confusion? Also, If it is not by default, can anyone recommend a good plugin(Free/paid) for the same.

Thanks

Comment: are you using magento EE (commerce Edition) ? because above feature is only available in EE

Comment: commerce Edition (Open Source)

Comment: OK, gift card functionality is only available in EE edition.Yo need to use third party modules..

Comment: okay.., Tnx You